# Python:Why does my code stops after printing first row of dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to enter contents from a file into a dictionary.My code prints first
row as expected but then fails to print second line onwards

I tried to use DictReader instead of Reader module
Following is my code:

```
import csv
def read_portfolio(filename):
    portfolio = {}
    with open (filename) as f:
        rows = csv.reader(f)
        headers= next(f)
        for row in rows:
            #portfolio[row['name']] = {'shares': row['shares'], 'price': row['price']}
            portfolio=[{'name':row[0],'shares':row[1],"price":row[1]}]
    return portfolio

myportfolio = read_portfolio('portfolio.csv')
print(myportfolio)
```

Comment: you're re-initializing `portfolio` on each pass of the loop instead of appending the values to the dict.

Comment: How to append a dictionary? isn't think append is the method of list?

Comment: The commented-out line looks like it would have worked, possibly with some changes in how you get the values from `row`.

Comment: You don't append values to a dict. You *assign a value to a given key*. It Isn't clear **what you expect as your result*. You could initialize `portfolio` as. `list` then use `portfolio.append({'name':row[0],'shares':row[1],"price":row[1]}])`.

Comment: In which case, you probably should just use `csv.DictReader`, they your whole code would just be `portfolio = list(csv.DictReader(f))` (with no loop)

Comment: The code prints : 'AA': {'name': 'AA', 'shares': '100', 'price': '100'}, I want to get' AA' at the beginning

Comment: The commented line does that.

Answer (score 0):

you should assign to a key of the dictionary, not reassign the variable. Change

```
portfolio=[{'name':row[0],'shares':row[1],"price":row[1]}]
```

to

```
portfolio[row[0]]={'shares':row[1],"price":row[1]}
```